# Отображение ответов, помеченных как «общие», в профиле

Tags: предложение, общие-сообщения

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130243/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-mingw-%D0%BA-sublime-text-2/516329#516329) автор разместил ответ в теле вопроса. Т. к. ув-мый Sam Sky давно неактивен, я самостоятельно перенёс ответ из вопроса, пометив его «общим». Но помеченный «общим» ответ на вопрос «Как прикрутить MinGW к Sublime Text 2» теперь отображается в моём профиле [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199934/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85):

[MinGW http://pokit.org/get/img/b870feb323a89a065c4ee51fa13249cf.jpg](http://pokit.org/get/img/b870feb323a89a065c4ee51fa13249cf.jpg)

и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199934/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85?tab=answers):

[MinGW http://pokit.org/get/img/b6d901e275f82a49df23cfd1749e824c.jpg](http://pokit.org/get/img/b6d901e275f82a49df23cfd1749e824c.jpg)

Это не мой ответ, равно как репутация, вне зависимости, положительная ли она или отрицательная. Полагаю, что следует исключить информацию об общих ответах (а вероятно, и вопросах) из профиля.

Answer (score 3):

Репутацию за общий ответ вы не получите. Но авторство ответа остается за вами. Вы будете получать знаки, например за 10, 25 и 100 голосов.

Сайт всегда показывал общие вопросы и ответы вместе с остальными. Участники, имеющие достаточно много общих сообщений, привыкли находить их там же. Не стоит ломать привычное им поведение сайта.

Если хотите найти собственные ответы, не включая общие, можете составить соответствующий поисковый запрос.